# URL not found of static files using AWS cloudfront

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I have created a cloudfront distribution to load the static file. The domain name i get  is [this](http://d3pinform7a3hy.cloudfront.net) (d3pinform7a3hy.cloudfront.net) . Origin is [link](http://meetngreet18.com/css/font-awesome.min.css) (example.com/css/font-awesome.min.css) . I am trying to load the static file from the cdn using https://d3pinform7a3hy.cloudfront.net/css/font-awesome.min.css but getting not found.

**How can i access the file through cdn link ?**

Comment: Origin should be just `example.com`. Rest of the path is getting passed through.

Comment: My origin domain name is example.com and origin path is /css/font-awesome.min.css in origin settings.

Answer (score 0):

In the distribution setting, I believe you have setup the CNAME to point to meetngreet18.com. Also, if the origin domain is an S3 bucket, then it must have the folder named `css` and the `font-awesome.min.css`. If it's an EC2 instance, then it must serve requests at the path /css/* to serve the css.

What is your origin (S3/EC2) and how does your path pattern/origin path config look like in the distribution?